# C++ Reading character by character

Tags: c++, input

I need to read sequences of characters from the keyboard character by character and I have spent a few hours stuck and searching the web to no avail. Please tell me why this loop won't terminate. I'm sure the answer is so simple I can hit myself in the face afterwards.

```
char c;
c = cin.get()
while(cin.good())
{
   DoSomething(c);
   c = cin.get();
}
```

Why does this loop continue indefinitely and how can it be fixed???? I normally would use a string and a istringstream but I'm in a beginner programming course and unfortunately we're not allowed to do it our way or use any neat tricks. We were told specifically to use cin.

Comment: Try pressing Ctrl+Z or Ctrl+C to terminate.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

  char ch;
  while(cin >> ch){
    cout << " Char is : " << ch << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

at what point do you expect the input stream to ever become bad, or empty?

You can't read characters from stdin as it expects keyboard input - ie, it expects to have to wait a *very* long time for the user to press the next key.

So, decide on a character to quit reading, when that character is read, quit the loop.

Comment: good point I figured out to use the isspace() function in the condition and now it reads until whitespace.